# Name of the "object" next to an LCD

Tags: connector, lcd, remote

I opened up a remote I had and saw there were two soft "objects" next to the display in it. What is it's name and function?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Zebra strip. It connects the PCB to the display by having vertical conductive paths. The pitch between the conductive strips is finer than the spacing between the PCB pads so that it doesn't have to be aligned exactly. There are conductive contact areas on the glass LCD in the same pattern as on the PCB.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? I can't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: @Dampmaskin probably because it answers a question which is a duplicate.

Comment: And the question still has zero votes. Oh well. Not everything is for me to understand I guess.